# Error in the Jira custom groovy script post-function

Tags: groovy, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to create a post function that will create subtasks when creating a issue. 
I'm trying to create a post function that will create subtasks when creating a task. The amount of the subtask depends on the amount of custom fields filled.
Now there are only two fields [14098,14099], but then they can become more.
Jira v.6.3.10

```
import com.atlassian.jira.component.ComponentAccessor
import com.atlassian.jira.issue.MutableIssue

def constantManager = ComponentAccessor.getConstantsManager()
def issueManager = ComponentAccessor.getIssueManager()
def issueFactory = ComponentAccessor.getIssueFactory()
def subTaskManager = ComponentAccessor.getSubTaskManager()
def customFieldManager = ComponentAccessor.getCustomFieldManager()

def personFieldsIds = [14098,14099]

for (int personFieldsId:personFieldsIds){
def person = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject(personFieldsId)
def personValue = issue.getCustomFieldValue(person)
if (personValue){
MutableIssue newSubTask = issueFactory.getIssue()
newSubTask.setReporter(issue.reporter)
newSubTask.setAssignee(personValue?.getKey())
newSubTask.setSummary("Subtask for " + personValue?.getDisplayName())
newSubTask.setParentObject(issue)
newSubTask.setProjectObject(issue.getProjectObject())
newSubTask.setIssueTypeId(constantManager.getAllIssueTypeObjects().find{it.getName() == "Sub-task"}.id)
newSubTask.setDescription("Description for " + personValue?.getDisplayName())
Map<String,Object> newIssueParams = ["issue" : newSubTask] as Map<String,Object>
issueManager.createIssueObject(issue.reporter, newIssueParams)
subTaskManager.createSubTaskIssueLink(issue, newSubTask, issue.reporter)
}
}
```

Error log:

2019-05-29 11:30:12,079 ERROR [workflow.ScriptWorkflowFunction]: *************************************************************************************
2019-05-29 11:30:12,096 ERROR [workflow.ScriptWorkflowFunction]: Script function failed on issue: null, actionId: 1, file: 
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: customFieldManager for class: Script8
    at Script8.run(Script8.groovy:13)

[script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN7ko.png)
[err](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B5nzM.png)

Comment: please edit your question and provide the error message(s)

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the codes in your question and in your image are not equal and the errors don't fit, too.

However, first in the code you posted in the image, you actually don't have the property/variable customFieldManager. The line of getting the CustomFieldManager is missing.

Then the method `getCustomFieldObject` is expecting a value of type long: https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/6.3.10/com/atlassian/jira/issue/CustomFieldManager.html#getCustomFieldObject(java.lang.Long)
So, either you can change it to:

```
def person = customFieldManager.getCustomFieldObject(personFieldsId as Long)
```

or

```
def personFieldsIds = [14098L, 14099L]
```